# Installing Imap PHP extension on VPS

Tags: php, imap, dreamhost

I've been trying to install the imap extension on my server by doing the following:

```
sudo apt-get install php5-imap
sudo /etc/init.d/httpd2 restart apache2-ps----
```

Everything seems to work fine, the extension has been installed, Apache has restarted. I even tried to re-install the extension and got a message that it was already installed and that nothing was updated.

Now , when I go to the Status Report of my Drupal installation, I still get the following message.

```
Mailhandler requires that PHP's IMAP extension is enabled 
in order to function properly.
```

After doing a lot of Googling, I'm still stuck...

- Is there a way to verify that the imap extension has been correctly installed?
- Do I need any further action in order to enable it?

Edit

---

Info from phpinfo(), suggests that IMAP is installed,
therefore it may not be a server issue!

```
imap

IMAP c-Client Version   2007b
SSL Support enabled
Kerberos Support    enabled
```

Comment: What does `phpinfo();` tell you?

Comment: http://drupal.org/node/1234962

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved, it's actually Drupal related.

There's no issue with the way the extension was installed but the notification in Drupal doesn't disappear. leading you to believe that the problem hasn't been fixed.

```
IMAP    Enabled
Mailhandler requires that PHP's IMAP extension 
is enabled in order to function properly.
```

With a closer look, I could see that IMAP was actually enabled...